# Deserializing JSON string to a non-predefined object in C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, jsonconvert

I have a  JSON response from an API with a number of data. What I actually need is just a few of the items in the result.
Is there a way I can deserialize it to a C# object without having to define a class with members to correspond with all the items in the returned JSON. 
Or, must I have to define a class that has properties to correspond to all the member elements in the returned JSON?

This is a sample of the returned JSON

```
{"status":"success","message":"Tx Fetched","data":{"txid":993106,"txref":"rgdk3viu.h","flwref":"FLW-MOCK-08efd1cb507f60ae50f7ebab4b27d234","devicefingerprint":"1d3d89c867abc0a84e1e167e2430456a","cycle":"one-time","amount":240,"currency":"NGN","chargedamount":243.36,"appfee":3.36,"merchantfee":0,"merchantbearsfee":0,"chargecode":"00","chargemessage":"Please enter the OTP sent to your mobile number 080****** and email te**@rave**.com","authmodel":"PIN","ip":"197.211.58.150","narration":"CARD Transaction ","status":"successful","vbvcode":"00","vbvmessage":"successful","authurl":"N/A","acctcode":null,"acctmessage":null,"paymenttype":"card","paymentid":"6490","fraudstatus":"ok","chargetype":"normal","createdday":0,"createddayname":"SUNDAY","createdweek":1,"createdmonth":0,"createdmonthname":"JANUARY","createdquarter":1,"createdyear":2020,"createdyearisleap":true,"createddayispublicholiday":0,"createdhour":17,"createdminute":40,"createdpmam":"pm","created":"2020-01-05T17:40:50.000Z","customerid":248784,"custphone":"080123456789","custnetworkprovider":"UNKNOWN PROVIDER","custname":"Chukwuemeka Ekeleme","custemail":"emeka.ekeleme@gmail.com","custemailprovider":"GMAIL","custcreated":"2020-01-05T17:40:50.000Z","accountid":85976,"acctbusinessname":"Learning Suite Nigeria","acctcontactperson":"Joshua Ndukwe","acctcountry":"NG","acctbearsfeeattransactiontime":0,"acctparent":1,"acctvpcmerchant":"N/A","acctalias":null,"acctisliveapproved":0,"orderref":"URF_1578246050675_7111835","paymentplan":null,"paymentpage":null,"raveref":"RV31578246049488BB4A178915","amountsettledforthistransaction":240,"card":{"expirymonth":"09","expiryyear":"22","cardBIN":"553188","last4digits":"2950","brand":" CREDIT","issuing_country":"NIGERIA NG","card_tokens":[{"embedtoken":"flw-t1nf-4542d3a9e7155f1512344b02aaa46255-m03k","shortcode":"534fb","expiry":"9999999999999"}],"type":"MASTERCARD","life_time_token":"flw-t1nf-4542d3a9e7155f1512344b02aaa46255-m03k"},"meta":[]}}
```

I have tried the following code

```
 using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paymentVerificationRequestData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(paymentVerificationRequestData.Url, content))
            {
                string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var paymentVerificationResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RaveVerificationResponseData>(apiResponse);
                string msg = paymentVerificationResponse.chargemessage;

                return Content(msg);

            }
        }
```

but all the elements in paymentVerificationResponse including chargemessage are all null or 0

My application is running on ASP.Net-Core 3.1

Comment: You can enumerate an object properties an parse required

Comment: better you have create c# class and deserialize  it

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, Please could you guide me on how to do that?

Comment: Yes, `JObject.Parse(" your string ")` from the Json.Net library.

Comment: @Crowcoder, Please I don't understand your response

Comment: @MahdiAnjam: That's not always the case. Sometimes you really want to be to parse JSON dynamically.

Comment: @JonSkeet if used api and call it every hours not good to create class? almost  anyone used api need to cahnge it to cleanModel for use it

Comment: @MahdiAnjam: In many cases, yes, but not every case. At the very least, it would be worth accepting that there *are* such cases, even if you might want to say that *usually* it's worth creating a class.

Comment: What I'm talking about is described in Petttkous Pett's answer but you have been shown many good options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api response is a nested object. You have some options. You can use `object` and access to a key using `Reflection`. for example for `chargemessage`:

```
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json);
var data = deserializedObject.GetType().GetProperty("data").GetValue(deserializedObject);
var chargemessage = data.GetType().GetProperty("chargemessage").GetValue(data);
```

Another option is defining a class with the keys that you need and deserializing the JSON using with.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DataClass data { get; set;}
}
public class DataClass
{
    public string chargemessage { get; set;}
}
```

after deserializing you can access the values like this:

```
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
var status = deserializedObject.data.chargemessage;
```

Comment: Please see my updated question  showing where i tried to do as you are suggesting but I am getting null for the elements of the deserialized object. Please see if there is something I am not getting right there

Comment: It's because your JSON has is a nested object. Therefore you must define a class and as a result you will have: `paymentVerificationResponse.data.chargemessage`. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have a class that corresponds to **all** properties in Json, you can create a class only with needed properties and deserialize it.

```
public class Result
{
    public string Status { get; set;}
    public string Message { get; set;}
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
```

Comment: Are you saying that I can now possibly get result.Message after that ? I asked this question because I just tried to do that but I am not getting a response

Comment: @Josh exactly, make sure you don't have any unescaped characters, it should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the json string using:

```
var json = JObject.Parse("JsonString");
```

Then you can access each key using `var status = (StatusEnum)json["yourKey"]`

Or if you are not sure if the key will always be present you can check by using

```
json.ContainsKey("yourKey")
```

or you can try parsing it right away

```
if (json.TryGetValue("yourKey", out var yourKey))
{
   //property found
   var yourProperty = (YourType)yourKey;
}
else
{ 
   //doesn't contain the property
}
```

or even by using

```
if (json["yourKey"] != null)
{
   //property found
}
```

Hope this helps.